# What is the FOV on the various Starman cameras?

Tags: spacex, photography, tesla-roadster

I'm trying to find the Field of View of the cameras used by Starman. Anyone know what it was? Thanks!

[image]

Comment: I would guess a moderate wide angle lens to avoid larger distances between cameras and the car. The car and the camera mounts should fit under the fairing. I think unfolding of camera mounts should be avoided. Keep things as simple as possible, but not more.

Comment: It might be easier to look at many images of the payload mounting and guess where the cameras are, then use the known (published) dimensions of a roadster to back-calculate the FOVs. If you are doing a simulation (e.g. Blender), the best thing to do is to play with the positions and FOVs to match the size of the Earth and features on the car. Even if someone types "camera 3's FOV is 57 degrees" in an answer, you can't be sure if its right. Blender has several features to find the best internal camera parameters so that key points in a render will match key points in an external image.

Comment: @uhoh That will be what I do in the end, it's just nice to have a starting point, especially for before I have the full model included.

Answer (score 2):

I compared this to the last picture taken with Starman. I'm assuming that this happened about 12 hours after launch, as Elon indicated the batteries would last.

[image]

Playing around with a simple model I created, I get a good match in the Earth size and phase angle in this shot. The field of view that I used is 45 degrees, thus I'm assuming the cameras are pretty close to 45 degrees in Field of View.

[image]